# Export Build/Release logs automatically on Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Pretty much everything is in title, I am looking for a way to export Agent logs once build/release is completed automatically, so that I can make a POST request to slack with those logs and developers don't need to access Azure devops and lose time.

I found GET this (https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/logs?api-version=5.1 ) but it is not what I am looking for.

If anyone knows or has any idea please let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I kinda found the answer, it's not documented but it works, https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/logs/10,

This solves what I am looking for, thanks.

Comment: Hi Stefan, Really thanks for sharing your solution here, if possible, you could accept it as the answer, so it could also help other community members who meet the same issue as yours.